# How would someone send data from React to Node (Sails to be precise)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, sails.js

I'm doing all the 'calculations' on the backend, but the user inputs happen on the React side (obviously :)). How can I pass a simple data pice to the Sails backend?

I said 'simple' because it would be a number (like this - 201805). On every click event, it could be a different number so is it possible to make some post request to the Sails (Node) backend everytime it changes, in order for the backend to do the necessary calculations everytime a user changes the value on the frontend.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It really doesn't matter which backend your using, it really just relies on React or whatever you're doing on your frontend and the format of the data (JSON).

In React, you can use `state` and the `onChange` hook for your inputs and update and send the updated data over to your server (backend) on submit, with `fetch` or a library like `axios`, which are for making requests to an API.

So for example:

```
class ExampleForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    dataToSend: '',
  }

  onChange = (e) => { // On input change
    this.setState({
      dataToSend: e.target.value
    })
  }

  onSubmit = () => {
      axios.post('/api/whatever', { this.state.dataToSend })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <label>Number</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            value={this.state.dataToSend}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
        <button type='submit'>Send Data</Button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```